# MERGE Statement in T-SQL Trigger Working Sporadically

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, merge

The issue I am having involves a MERGE statement used in an AFTER Insert trigger. The situation is that we have a table that is a history of inventory transactions, call this Table A. When a record is inserted into Table A, an AFTER INSERT trigger is fired. This trigger contains two MERGE statements to update Table B and then update Table C. The MERGE for Table C joins to Table B so we are not repeating calculations. Table B and Table C are two separate rollups of inventory transactions  to show what inventory is available. Below I have pasted some pseudo-code of the trigger consists of.

This works 80% of the time. The other 20% of the time the updates are not occurring. I have verified it is not a logic issue as if we were to manually run the merge statements for the inserted record then they would update the target records in Table B and Table C appropriately. Have used profiler and extended events to try to capture instances that this is not updating correctly to no avail as there are thousands of transactions being processed. A trigger is the only option I believe I have as the client requires the updates to be real-time. I have verified all my merge statements are correct, it just seems as if when the trigger is firing it is not picking up records from the inserted table appropriately. I have accounted for multiple records in the inserted by grouping by the unique key we are matching on in the merge so it is not this. At a loss and will take any suggestions.

EDIT: Replacing pseudo code with actual code

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trig_HBS2013_ILTHUpdateILCandILBC_DW]
ON [RELLDW].[dbo].[ItemLotTransactionHistory]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'relldom\hbsprocessad'
 MERGE [dbo].[ItemLotCurrent] WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS target
    USING (SELECT 
                ----On Hand (LocalExtAmt)
                SUM(CAST( 
                        ISNULL(ILC.ILC_dc_lclExtAmtCostOnHand, 0)
                            + CASE
                                WHEN ILTH.ILTH_nv_RecordType = 'POR'
                                    OR ILTH.ILTH_nv_TransactionType = 'WIP Out'
                                    THEN ISNULL(ILTH.ILTH_dc_LocalExtAmt, 0)
                                WHEN ILTH.ILTH_nv_RecordType = 'FUL'
                                    OR ILTH.ILTH_nv_TransactionType = 'WIP In'      
                                    THEN ISNULL(ILTH.ILTH_dc_LocalExtAmt, 0) * -1
                                END
                     AS decimal(23, 10))) AS ILC_dc_lclExtAmtCostOnHand,
                ----On Hand (QtyBase)
                SUM(CAST(   
                        ISNULL(ILC.ILC_dc_QtyOnHand, 0) +
                                CASE
                                    WHEN ILTH.ILTH_nv_RecordType = 'POR'
                                        OR ILTH.ILTH_nv_TransactionType = 'WIP Out'
                                        THEN ISNULL(ILTH.ILTH_dc_QuantityBase, 0)
                                    WHEN ILTH.ILTH_nv_RecordType = 'FUL'
                                        OR ILTH.ILTH_nv_TransactionType = 'WIP In'      
                                        THEN ISNULL(ILTH.ILTH_dc_QuantityBase, 0) * -1
                                    END 
                         AS decimal(23, 10))) AS ILC_dc_QtyOnHand,
                MAX(CAST(ILTH.ILTH_id_ItemCode AS uniqueidentifier)) AS ILC_id_Item,
                CAST(MAX(ILTH.ILTH_id_lotcode) AS uniqueidentifier) AS ILC_id_ItemLot
            FROM inserted AS ILTH
                --Item Lot Curent
                    LEFT JOIN RELLDW.dbo.ItemLotCurrent AS ILC
                        ON ILTH.ILTH_id_LotCode = ILC.ILC_id_ItemLot
            WHERE  ILTH.ILTH_nv_recordtype <> 'TRANS' AND ILTH.ILTH_id_LotCode IS NOT NULL
            GROUP BY 
                ILTH.ILTH_id_lotcode
            )
        AS source (
            ILC_dc_lclExtAmtCostOnHand,
            ILC_dc_QtyOnHand,
            ILC_id_Item,
            ILC_id_ItemLot
            )          
    ON (target.ILC_id_itemlot = source.ILC_id_itemlot)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
        UPDATE SET 
            ILC_dc_lclExtAmtCostOnHand = source.ILC_dc_lclExtAmtCostOnHand,
            ILC_dc_QtyOnHand = source.ILC_dc_QtyOnHand,
            ILC_id_Item = source.ILC_id_Item,
            ILC_id_ItemLot = source.ILC_id_ItemLot,
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN   
        INSERT (,
            ILC_dc_lclExtAmtCostOnHand,
            ILC_dc_QtyOnHand,
            ILC_id_Item,
            ILC_id_ItemLot
        ) 
        VALUES (
            source.ILC_dc_lclExtAmtCostOnHand,
            source.ILC_dc_QtyOnHand,
            source.ILC_id_Item,
            source.ILC_id_ItemLot
            );

UPDATE dbo.ItemLotTransactionHistory
SET ILTH_nv_ILCUpdate='Updated'
WHERE ILTH_ID IN (select ilth_id from inserted);

MERGE [dbo].[ItemLotBinCurrent] WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS target
    USING (
        SELECT 
            CAST(CASE 
                    WHEN ILBCSub.CostType = 861430003
                        THEN (ISNULL(ILC.ILC_dc_lclExtAmtCostOnHand,0) /(CASE WHEN (ISNULL(ILC.ILC_dc_QtyOnHand,0) = 0 )THEN 1 ELSE ISNULL(ILC.ILC_dc_QtyOnHand,0) END)) * (ISNULL(ILBCSub.ILBC_dc_OldQtyBase,0)+ISNULL(ILBCSub.ILBC_dc_Qtybase,0)) 
                            ELSE
                                CASE 
                                    WHEN (ISNULL(ILBCSub.ILBC_dc_OldqtyBase,0) + ISNULL(ILBCSub.ILBC_dc_QtyBase,0)) <= 0
                                        THEN 0
                                    ELSE (ISNULL(ILC.ILC_dc_lclExtAmtCostOnHand,0) /(CASE WHEN ISNULL(ILC.ILC_dc_QtyOnHand,0) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE ISNULL(ILC.ILC_dc_QtyOnHand,0) END)) * (ISNULL(ILBCSub.ILBC_dc_OldQtyBase,0)+ISNULL(ILBCSub.ILBC_dc_Qtybase,0))
                                END 
                    END AS decimal(23,10)) AS ILBC_dc_localExtAmt,
            ISNULL(ILBCSub.ILBC_dc_OldQtyBase,0)+ISNULL(ILBCSub.ILBC_dc_Qtybase,0) AS ILBC_dc_QuantityBase,
            ILBCSub.ILBC_id_BaseUOM AS ILBC_id_BaseUOM,
            ILBCSub.ILBC_id_Bin AS ILBC_id_bin,
            ILBCSub.ILBC_id_Item AS ILBC_id_item,
            ILBCSub.ILBC_id_LocalCurrency AS ILBC_id_localCurrency,
            ILBCSub.ILBC_id_Lot AS ILBC_id_lot,
            ILBCSub.ILBC_id_warehouse AS ILBC_id_warehouse,
            ILBCSub.ILBC_nv_baseuomcode AS ILBC_nv_baseuomcode,
            ILBCSub.ILBC_nv_bincode AS ILBC_nv_bincode,
            ILBCSub.ILBC_nv_itemcode AS ILBC_nv_itemcode,
            ILBCSub.ILBC_nv_itemshortdesc AS ILBC_nv_itemshortdesc,
            ILBCSub.ILBC_nv_LocalCurrencyCode AS ILBC_nv_localcurrencycode,
            ILBCSub.ILBC_nv_localcurrencyshortdesc AS ILBC_nv_localcurrencyshortdesc,
            ILBCSub.ILBC_nv_lot AS ILBC_nv_lot,
            ILBCSub.ILBC_nv_WarehouseCode AS ILBC_nv_warehousecode

    FROM(SELECT
            ISNULL(ILBCSum.ILBC_dc_localextamt,0) AS ILBC_dc_lclextamt,
            ISNULL(ILBCSum.ILBC_dc_quantityBase,0) AS ILBC_dc_qtyBase,  
            ILBCSum.ILBC_id_BaseUOM AS ILBC_id_BaseUOM,
            COALESCE(ILBCSum.ILBC_id_Bin, ILBC.ILBC_id_bin) AS ILBC_id_bin,
            ILBCSum.ILBC_id_Item AS ILBC_id_item,
            ILBCSum.ILBC_id_LocalCurrency AS ILBC_id_localCurrency,
            COALESCE(ILBCSum.ILBC_id_Lot, ILBC.ILBC_id_lot) AS ILBC_id_lot,
            ILBCSum.ILBC_id_warehouse AS ILBC_id_warehouse,
            ILBCSum.ILBC_nv_baseuomcode AS ILBC_nv_baseuomcode,
            ILBCSum.ILBC_nv_bincode AS ILBC_nv_bincode,
            ILBCSum.ILBC_nv_itemcode AS ILBC_nv_itemcode,
            ILBCSum.ILBC_nv_itemshortdesc AS ILBC_nv_itemshortdesc,
            ILBCSum.ILBC_nv_LocalCurrencyCode AS ILBC_nv_localcurrencycode,
            ILBCSum.ILBC_nv_localcurrencyshortdesc AS ILBC_nv_localcurrencyshortdesc,
            ILBCSum.ILBC_nv_lot AS ILBC_nv_lot,
            ILBCSum.ILBC_nv_WarehouseCode AS ILBC_nv_warehousecode,
            ILBCSum.CostType AS CostType,
            ILBC.ILBC_dc_quantitybase AS ILBC_dc_OldQtyBase

        FROM dbo.ItemLotBinCurrent AS ILBC 
        ----Sum up the net transaction
        FULL JOIN(
            SELECT
                SUM(ISNULL(ILBCNet.ILBC_dc_localExtAmt,0)) AS ILBC_dc_LocalExtAmt,
                SUM(ISNULL(ILBCNet.ILBC_dc_QuantityBase,0)) AS ILBC_dc_QuantityBase,
                MAX(ILBCNet.ILBC_id_BaseUOM) AS ILBC_id_BaseUOM,
                ILBCNet.ILBC_id_Bin AS ILBC_id_bin,
                MAX(ILBCNet.ILBC_id_Item) AS ILBC_id_item,
                MAX(ILBCNet.ILBC_id_LocalCurrency) AS ILBC_id_localCurrency,
                ILBCNet.ILBC_id_Lot AS ILBC_id_lot,
                MAX(ILBCNet.ILBC_id_warehouse) AS ILBC_id_warehouse,
                MAX(ILBCNet.ILBC_nv_baseuomcode) AS ILBC_nv_baseuomcode,
                MAX(ILBCNet.ILBC_nv_bincode) AS ILBC_nv_bincode,
                MAX(ILBCNet.ILBC_nv_itemcode) AS ILBC_nv_itemcode,
                MAX(ILBCNet.ILBC_nv_itemshortdesc) AS ILBC_nv_itemshortdesc,
                MAX(ILBCNet.ILBC_nv_LocalCurrencyCode) AS ILBC_nv_localcurrencycode,
                MAX(ILBCNet.ILBC_nv_localcurrencyshortdesc) AS ILBC_nv_localcurrencyshortdesc,
                MAX(ILBCNet.ILBC_nv_lot) AS ILBC_nv_lot,
                MAX(ILBCNet.ILBC_nv_WarehouseCode) AS ILBC_nv_warehousecode,
                MAX(ILBCNet.ILBC_int_costtype) AS CostType
            ----POSITIVE TRANSACTIONS---
            FROM(
                SELECT
                    CAST(CASE
                            WHEN ILTH.ILTH_nv_RecordType = 'POR' OR ILTH.ILTH_nv_TransactionType='WIP Out'
                                THEN ISNULL(ILTH.ILTH_dc_LocalExtAmt, 0)
                            WHEN ILTH.ILTH_nv_TransactionType = 'TRANS'
                                THEN 
                                    CASE 
                                        WHEN ILTH.ILTH_id_BinIn = ILTH.ILTH_id_BinOut
                                            THEN 0
                                        ELSE ISNULL(ILTH.ILTH_dc_LocalExtAmt, 0)
                                    END
                                ELSE 0
                        END AS decimal(23,10)) AS ILBC_dc_localExtAmt,
                    CAST(CASE
                            WHEN ILTH.ILTH_nv_RecordType = 'POR' OR ILTH.ILTH_nv_TransactionType ='WIP Out'
                                THEN ISNULL(ILTH.ILTH_dc_QuantityBase, 0)
                            WHEN ILTH.ILTH_nv_TransactionType='TRANS'
                                THEN 
                                    CASE 
                                        WHEN ILTH.ILTH_id_BinIn = ILTH.ILTH_id_BinOut
                                            THEN 0
                                        ELSE ISNULL(ILTH.ILTH_dc_QuantityBase, 0)
                                    END
                                ELSE 0
                            END AS decimal(23,10))AS ILBC_dc_QuantityBase,
                    CAST(ILTH.ILTH_id_BaseUofMCode AS uniqueidentifier)AS ILBC_id_BaseUOM,
                    CAST(CASE 
                            WHEN ILTH.ILTH_nv_RecordType = 'POR' 
                            OR ILTH.ILTH_nv_transactionType = 'WIP Out'
                                THEN ILTH.ILTH_id_binin
                            WHEN ILTH.ILTH_nv_TransactionType='TRANS'
                                THEN ILTH.ILTH_id_binin
                        END AS uniqueidentifier)AS ILBC_id_Bin,
                    CAST(ILTH.ILTH_id_ItemCode AS uniqueidentifier)AS ILBC_id_Item,
                    CAST(ILTH.ILTH_id_LocalCurrencyCode AS uniqueidentifier)AS ILBC_id_LocalCurrency,
                    CAST(ILTH.ILTH_id_LotCode AS uniqueidentifier)AS ILBC_id_Lot,
                    CAST(CASE 
                            WHEN ILTH.ILTH_nv_RecordType = 'POR' 
                            OR ILTH.ILTH_nv_transactionType = 'WIP Out'
                                THEN ILTH.ILTH_id_WarehouseCodein 
                            WHEN ILTH.ILTH_nv_TransactionType='TRANS' 
                                THEN ILTH.ILTH_id_WarehouseCodein 
                        END AS uniqueidentifier)AS ILBC_id_warehouse,
                    CAST(ILTH.ILTH_nv_BaseUofMCode AS nvarchar(64))AS ILBC_nv_baseuomcode,
                    CAST(CASE 
                            WHEN ILTH.ILTH_nv_RecordType = 'POR' 
                            OR ILTH.ILTH_nv_transactionType = 'WIP Out'
                                THEN ILTH.ILTH_nv_Binin
                            WHEN ILTH.ILTH_nv_TransactionType='TRANS'
                                THEN ILTH.ILTH_nv_Binin
                        END AS nvarchar(64))AS ILBC_nv_bincode,
                    CAST(ILTH.ILTH_nv_ItemCode AS nvarchar(64))AS ILBC_nv_itemcode,
                    CAST(ILTH.ILTH_nv_ItemShortDesc AS nvarchar(128))AS ILBC_nv_itemshortdesc,
                    CAST(ILTH.ILTH_nv_LocalCurrencyCode AS nvarchar(64))AS ILBC_nv_LocalCurrencyCode,
                    CAST(WHS.WHS_nv_LclCurrencyShortDesc AS nvarchar(128))AS ILBC_nv_localcurrencyshortdesc,
                    CAST(ILTH.ILTH_nv_LotCode AS nvarchar(64))AS ILBC_nv_lot,
                    CAST(CASE 
                            WHEN ILTH.ILTH_nv_RecordType = 'POR' 
                            OR ILTH.ILTH_nv_transactionType = 'WIP Out'
                                THEN ILTH.ILTH_nv_WarehouseCodein
                            WHEN ILTH.ILTH_nv_TransactionType='TRANS'
                                THEN ILTH.ILTH_nv_WarehouseCodein
                        END AS nvarchar(64))AS ILBC_nv_WarehouseCode,
                CAST(ILTH.ILTH_int_costtype AS nvarchar(64)) AS ILBC_int_costtype
                FROM inserted AS ILTH
                    LEFT JOIN dbo.warehouseprofile AS WHS
                        ON ILTH.ILTH_id_warehousecodein = WHS.WHS_id_warehouse
                WHERE ILTH.ILTH_id_warehousecodein IS NOT NULL
                    AND ILTH.ILTH_id_binin IS NOT NULL
                    AND ILTH.ILTH_nv_TrnType NOT IN ('IL Adj Up Out' , 'IL Adj Up In' , 'IL Adj Down Out', 'IL Adj Down In')
                    AND (ILTH.ILTH_nv_RecordType = 'POR' OR ILTH.ILTH_nv_TransactionType IN ('WIP Out','TRANS'))
            -----NEGATIVE TRANSACTIONS---
            UNION ALL 
            SELECT
                    CAST(CASE
                            WHEN ILTH.ILTH_nv_RecordType = 'FUL' OR ILTH.ILTH_nv_TransactionType='WIP In'
                                THEN  ISNULL(ILTH.ILTH_dc_LocalExtAmt, 0) * -1
                            WHEN ILTH.ILTH_nv_TransactionType='TRANS'       
                                THEN 
                                    CASE
                                        WHEN ILTH.ILTH_id_BinIn = ILTH.ILTH_id_BinOut
                                            THEN 0
                                        ELSE ISNULL(ILTH.ILTH_dc_LocalExtAmt, 0) * -1
                                    END
                                ELSE 0
                        END AS decimal(23, 10)) AS ILBC_dc_LocalExtAmt,
                    CAST(CASE
                            WHEN ILTH.ILTH_nv_RecordType = 'FUL' OR ILTH.ILTH_nv_TransactionType ='WIP In' 
                                THEN ISNULL(ILTH.ILTH_dc_quantityBase, 0) * -1
                            WHEN ILTH.ILTH_nv_TransactionType='TRANS'       
                                THEN 
                                    CASE
                                        WHEN ILTH.ILTH_id_BinIn = ILTH.ILTH_id_BinOut 
                                            THEN 0
                                        ELSE ISNULL(ILTH.ILTH_dc_quantityBase, 0) * -1
                                    END
                            ELSE 0
                        END AS decimal(23,10))AS ILBC_dc_QuantityBase,
                    CAST(ILTH.ILTH_id_BaseUofMCode AS uniqueidentifier)AS ILBC_id_BaseUOM,
                    CAST(CASE
                            WHEN ILTH.ILTH_nv_RecordType = 'FUL' 
                            OR ILTH.ILTH_nv_TransactionType ='WIP In' 
                                THEN ILTH.ILTH_id_BinOut
                            WHEN ILTH.ILTH_nv_TransactionType='TRANS'
                                THEN ILTH.ILTH_id_BinOut
                        END AS uniqueidentifier)AS ILBC_id_Bin,
                    CAST(ILTH.ILTH_id_ItemCode AS uniqueidentifier)AS ILBC_id_Item,
                    CAST(ILTH.ILTH_id_LocalCurrencyCode AS uniqueidentifier)AS ILBC_id_LocalCurrency,
                    CAST(ILTH.ILTH_id_LotCode AS uniqueidentifier)AS ILBC_id_Lot,
                    CAST(CASE
                            WHEN ILTH.ILTH_nv_RecordType = 'FUL' 
                            OR ILTH.ILTH_nv_TransactionType ='WIP In' 
                                THEN ILTH.ILTH_id_WarehouseCodeOut
                            WHEN ILTH.ILTH_nv_TransactionType='TRANS'
                                THEN ILTH.ILTH_id_WarehouseCodeOut
                        END AS uniqueidentifier)AS ILBC_id_warehouse,
                    CAST(ILTH.ILTH_nv_BaseUofMCode AS nvarchar(64))AS ILBC_nv_baseuomcode,
                    CAST(CASE
                            WHEN ILTH.ILTH_nv_RecordType = 'FUL' 
                            OR ILTH.ILTH_nv_TransactionType ='WIP In' 
                                THEN ILTH.ILTH_nv_BinOut 
                            WHEN ILTH.ILTH_nv_TransactionType='TRANS'
                                THEN ILTH.ILTH_nv_BinOut 
                        END AS nvarchar(64))AS ILBC_nv_bincode,
                    CAST(ILTH.ILTH_nv_ItemCode AS nvarchar(64))AS ILBC_nv_itemcode,
                    CAST(ILTH.ILTH_nv_ItemShortDesc AS nvarchar(128))AS ILBC_nv_itemshortdesc,
                    CAST(ILTH.ILTH_nv_LocalCurrencyCode AS nvarchar(64))AS ILBC_nv_LocalCurrencyCode,
                    CAST(WHS.WHS_nv_LclCurrencyShortDesc AS nvarchar(128))AS ILBC_nv_localcurrencyshortdesc,
                    CAST(ILTH.ILTH_nv_LotCode AS nvarchar(64))AS ILBC_nv_lot,
                    CAST(CASE
                            WHEN ILTH.ILTH_nv_RecordType = 'FUL' 
                            OR ILTH.ILTH_nv_TransactionType ='WIP In' 
                                THEN ILTH.ILTH_nv_WarehouseCodeOut 
                            WHEN ILTH.ILTH_nv_TransactionType='TRANS'
                                THEN ILTH.ILTH_nv_WarehouseCodeOut 
                        END AS nvarchar(64))AS ILBC_WarehouseCode,
                    CAST(ILTH.ILTH_int_costtype AS nvarchar(64)) AS ILBC_int_costtype
            FROM inserted AS ILTH
                    LEFT JOIN dbo.warehouseprofile AS WHS
                        ON ILTH.ILTH_id_warehousecodein = WHS.WHS_id_warehouse
            WHERE ILTH.ILTH_id_warehousecodeout IS NOT NULL
                AND ILTH.ILTH_id_binout IS NOT NULL
                AND ILTH.ILTH_nv_TrnType NOT IN ('IL Adj Up Out' , 'IL Adj Up In' , 'IL Adj Down Out', 'IL Adj Down In')
                AND (ILTH.ILTH_nv_RecordType = 'FUL'OR ILTH.ILTH_nv_TransactionType IN ('WIP In','TRANS'))
                ) AS ILBCNet
        WHERE ILBCNet.ILBC_id_bin is not null
        GROUP BY 
            ILBCNet.ILBC_id_bin,
            ILBCNet.ILBC_id_lot
        ) AS ILBCSum
            ON ILBC.ILBC_id_lot = ILBCSum.ILBC_id_lot
            AND ILBC.ILBC_id_bin = ILBCSum.ILBC_id_bin
        WHERE ISNULL(ILBC.ILBC_id_lot,ILBCSum.ILBC_id_lot) IN (Select ILTH.ILTH_id_lotcode From inserted AS ILTH GROUP BY ILTH.ILTH_id_lotcode)
                OR
                ISNULL(ILBCSum.ILBC_id_lot,ILBC.ILBC_id_lot) IN (Select ILTH.ILTH_id_lotcode From inserted AS ILTH GROUP BY ILTH.ILTH_id_lotcode)
            ) AS ILBCSub
        LEFT JOIN dbo.ItemLotCurrent AS ILC
            ON ILBCSub.ILBC_id_lot=ILC.ILC_id_itemlot
        )AS source
            (
            ILBC_dc_LocalExtAmt,
            ILBC_dc_QuantityBase,
            ILBC_id_BaseUOM,
            ILBC_id_Bin,
            ILBC_id_Item,
            ILBC_id_LocalCurrency,
            ILBC_id_Lot,
            ILBC_id_Warehouse,
            ILBC_nv_BaseUOMCode,
            ILBC_nv_BinCode,
            ILBC_nv_ItemCode,
            ILBC_nv_ItemShortDesc,
            ILBC_nv_LocalCurrencyCode,
            ILBC_nv_LocalCurrencyShortDesc,
            ILBC_nv_Lot,
            ILBC_nv_WarehouseCode
            )          
        ON target.ILBC_id_lot = source.ILBC_id_lot
            AND target.ILBC_id_bin=source.ILBC_id_bin
        WHEN MATCHED THEN 
            UPDATE SET 
                    ILBC_dc_LocalExtAmt=source.ILBC_dc_LocalExtAmt,
                    ILBC_dc_QuantityBase=source.ILBC_dc_QuantityBase,
                    ILBC_ModifiedOn=GetDate()
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN   
            INSERT (
                    ILBC_dc_LocalExtAmt,
                    ILBC_dc_QuantityBase,
                    ILBC_id_BaseUOM,
                    ILBC_id_Bin,
                    ILBC_id_Item,
                    ILBC_id_LocalCurrency,
                    ILBC_id_Lot,
                    ILBC_id_Warehouse,
                    ILBC_nv_BaseUOMCode,
                    ILBC_nv_BinCode,
                    ILBC_nv_ItemCode,
                    ILBC_nv_ItemShortDesc,
                    ILBC_nv_LocalCurrencyCode,
                    ILBC_nv_LocalCurrencyShortDesc,
                    ILBC_nv_Lot,
                    ILBC_nv_WarehouseCode,
                    ILBC_CreatedOn,
                    ILBC_ModifiedOn
                    ) 
            VALUES (
                    source.ILBC_dc_LocalExtAmt,
                    source.ILBC_dc_QuantityBase,
                    source.ILBC_id_BaseUOM,
                    source.ILBC_id_Bin,
                    source.ILBC_id_Item,
                    source.ILBC_id_LocalCurrency,
                    source.ILBC_id_Lot,
                    source.ILBC_id_Warehouse,
                    source.ILBC_nv_BaseUOMCode,
                    source.ILBC_nv_BinCode,
                    source.ILBC_nv_ItemCode,
                    source.ILBC_nv_ItemShortDesc,
                    source.ILBC_nv_LocalCurrencyCode,
                    source.ILBC_nv_LocalCurrencyShortDesc,
                    source.ILBC_nv_Lot,
                    source.ILBC_nv_WarehouseCode,
                    GetDate(),
                    GetDate()
                    );
UPDATE dbo.ItemLotTransactionHistory
SET ILTH_nv_ILBCUpdate='Yes'
WHERE ILTH_ID IN (SELECT ILTH_ID from inserted)
;

END
```

Comment: You could try replacing the MERGE statements with equivalent INSERTS and UPDATES.

Comment: Maybe show your actual code... instead of pseudocode... the devil is usually in the details and it will be much easier to find if we can see the entire code (even if it's lengthy)...

Comment: Tab, thanks for the suggestion. Will be trying that as more of a last resort as using a merge would be more ideal for not having to deal with checking if a record exists or not to insert/update.

Comment: I updated the post with the actual code.